# MATLAB file 7.3 corrupted when opening

Tags: matlab

Is anybody know the following error ?

```
Error using load
Unable to read MAT-file
E:\...\Filtering.mat: not a binary MAT-file.
Try LOAD -ASCII to read as text.
```

MATLAB file v7.3 seems to be corrupted.
Maybe someone have an idea for repairing the file ?

Thanks,

Comment: How do you **know** it's corrupted?  Have you been able to open up this file before?

Comment: try opening it with a text file editor, where you should be able to read the header text - for example : MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Wed Aug 05 16:00:24 2015  - post this in to your question

Comment: Could you upload the file somewhere?

Comment: Yes i was able to open it before. I can't upload it because It's too big !When I try to load the file as a ASCII file, I have this message:

Comment: When I try to load the file as a ASCII file, I have this message:`code` load ('E:\...\Filtering.mat','-ascii')
Error using load
Number of columns on line 2 of ASCII file G:\Echogram.mat must be the same as previous lines. `code`